# Quasi Stationary AC to "normal" AC, WindPowerPlants

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I'm discovering OpenModelica for few days and I would like to study the combination of solar panels and wind turbines to product electricity.

So, i decided to use WindPowerPlants library for the wind part. My start point is from the example WindPowerPlants.Examples.GenericPlantElectricRealData

I would like to have a storage system in load of the system. But I have trouble to understand how to transfer the electrical signal from Quasi-Stationary Multiphase (in output of the wind turbine) to AC multiphase to be able to transfer the power in the load.

Is there a simple solution to just not have QS ? I'm limited by the components of the quasi-stationary library from Modelica.

I'm open to any information, I have certainly missed something or misunderstood.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no coupling model between quasi static and transient AC systems available in the Modelica Standard Library. The reason for that is, that quasi static models rely on purely sinusoidal voltages and currents but the transient domain wave forms can not be pushed to be sinusoidal. One could only create a coupling model which for example maintains the active and reactive power balance between the quasi static and the transient side.

I recommend to use the components from `Modelica.Electrical.QuasiStationary.MultiPhase` package and avoid the usage of transient models at all. Even though the quasi static package is limited to linear systems, you should be able to find most of the components you need to perform your investigations. In case you need, for example, a controlled AC power load, the model `WindPowerPlants.Sources.IdealRealPowerConductance` can be used.

In terms of power flow analysis based on controlled loads and generators I may also draw your attention to the following libraries (see https://modelica.org/libraries):

- https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/PowerSystems (successor of Spot, version 1.0.0 is available)
- https://github.com/PowerGrids/PowerGrids (version 1.0.0 was just released a few days ago)

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I will look at PowerGrids library and try to find a solution to use this QS power into AC or DC.

Comment: I replaced the link to the outdated Spot library above by the PowerSystems library; it may make sense for you to also hava a looḱ at this library.

Comment: Oh ok ! I'm trying to understand also this one, but it's quite different for what i know.
Thanks you very much !

Comment: I just realised that you are one of the developpers of WindPowerPlants Library. Do you know a website where I could find others examples for this library ?